# Does anyone know a dark elementary os like plank theme?

Tags: settings, plank, pantheon

I've been switching distros quite frequently lately... And I'm the most familiar with elementary os and ubuntu.. Now I intalled eos again, and I've turned on dark mode. The thing is that the elementary os dark theme doesn't apply to plank as well, so now I'm stuck with all dark except for plank, which still uses the normal, default white plank theme. Is there any way I could get the plank theme to be dark as well. I found the default thing, however it makes the bar a lot smaller, and it doesn't look that elementary-like. Maybe a theme, Idk... Thanks :)

Comment: I was also looking into making it black, but I settled for transparent eventually, it only shows the icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can start to create your own plank theme.
If you just want a dark theme to use right away, look at https://github.com/ChildishGiant/elementary-dark-plank. It fits very well with the default dark theme on eOS.

Answer (score 0):

The default plank is small but it is dark, Dont know if this helps.